# Why is Info.plist getting overwritten in my cocoa touch framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, properties-file

I have created a cocoa touch framework in xcode. I have also created a `podspec` file for the same.
Next I imported my framework in my application by adding the created framework in the `podfile` of my application.

In my framework I added some values of type string inside the main `'<dict> ..</dict> '` object in the Info.plist file.
Now I try to call a method in my framework with content like so:

```
let path = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist")
let data = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
if data != nil {print (data!)}
```

but the print result does not contain any of the strings that I added in the `Info.plist` file. It just contains other values, except the ones I entered.

Why is the `Info.plist` getting overwritten? How can I get the strings I added in `Info.plist`, in code?

Answer (score 0):

As per your answer statement, "I imported my framework in my application"; you have imported the framework in your xyz application.

And, you have added new keys to the plist of your framework, as per your statement "In my framework I added some values of type string inside the main ' .. ' object in the Info.plist file."

Furthermore, as per your code snippet below, you are looking for those keys in the resources of your xyz project.

```
let path = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist")
```

Conclusion, You should look for these keys in the plist, which is in the resources of your framework.

Comment: but if the the above code snippet is inside a view controller of the framework then shouldn't it print values from framework's Info.plist file

Comment: also if i change the code like
'Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist")' it prints the contents of Info.plist from application i.e. xyz application